# Show Hyperlinks in Modal View of SharePoint 2013 for calculated column or defaul value of a field

Tags: 2013, list, hyperlink

For whatever reason, if you set a hyperlink within calculated column or place an url as default value for a field, in the modal view the hyperlink wont work and in the case of calculated column it will show the entire code.

Researched a lot, but so far not sure what will make it work.

Comment: You need to specify the SP version you are on, and the Formula you used

Comment: How you set hyperlink in calculated column? Can you provide me steps?

Comment: SPS 2013 Enterprise (latest SP level)
@DannyEngelmanNVP & @viraj

`code` =CONCATENATE("<a href=’”,”https://example.com/sites//General%20Documents/Forms/by%20Document%20Category.aspx?View={373A9A36-C01A-4616-BADA-065DEEBC44C0}&FilterField1=Agreement&FilterValue1=",Agreement Number,”’>”,Information,”</a>”) `code`

It works when viewed in SPS List, but wen u open the item in MODAL view it shows the code rather the link.
Selected as Numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML in Calculated Columns only works in **Views**

It will display the bare HTML in Forms, in Alerts, in Tree View, etc etc

Read the pros & cons of HTML+JavaScript in Calculated Columns at:

### https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How

Alternatively you can do it with Client Side Rendering on SP2013:

#### CSR /JSLink blogs

- (dec 2015) - [Pitfalls using CSR/JSLink](https://www.scnsoft.com/blog/pitfalls-of-using-jslink-with-sharepoint-apps-for-office-store)
- (aug 2014) - [Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) - Andrei Markeev
- (aug 2014) - [Client Side Rendering: List Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms) - Andrei Markeev
- (jan 2016) - [CSR overrides in detail](http://josharepoint.com/2016/01/14/sharepoint-2013-client-side-rendering-register-templates-overrides-in-detail/) - José Quinto
- (aug 2013) - [JSLink and Display Templates](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1.html) -Martin Hatch
- (dec 2012) - [SP 2013: Using the JSLink property to change the way your field or views are rendered in SharePoint 2013](https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013) - Tobias Zimmergren
- (dec 2012) - [SP 2013: Measuring performance on the JSLink property in SharePoint 2013](https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-measuring-performance-on-the-jslink-property-in-sharepoint-2013) - Tobias Zimmergren
- (jul 2013) - [5 facts about JSLink you might not know](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/5-facts-about-jslink-in-sharepoint-2013-you-might-not-know) - Anton Vishnyakov
- (may 2015) - [CSS registration & ScriptLink done the right way](http://yakovenkomax.com/cssregistration-and-scriptlink-done-the-right-way/) - Max Yokavenko

Comment: Is their an alternate option?

Comment: CSR is the alternate

Comment: With reference to JavaScript, can you help me ascerting if the Javascript code below is correct to point a field name in SPS 2013 List as Hyperlink.

`code` <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> var setColumnValue = function (column, linkVal) { var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + column + "']"); columnObj.val(linkVal); } $(document).ready(function() { setColumnValue('Apply','example.com'); }); </script> `code`

Any pointer will be of great benefit.

Comment: This code is impossible to read in a comment. Make it another question and post it in a code block, that way anyone can answer

Comment: raised as a new question in the forum. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180742/update-field-name-with-a-hyperlink-in-sps-2013-list