# update field name with a hyperlink in SPS 2013 List

Tags: list, url, hyperlink

I`ve tried using JavaScript to update the field name: Apply with a Hyperlink. However, for what ever reason the code is not working as expected, thanks to Rajesh Sitaraman for the Code.

Please find below the code for review -

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var setColumnValue = function (column, linkVal) {  
  var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + column + "']");         
   columnObj.val(linkVal);  
 }   
 $(document).ready(function() {
  setColumnValue('Apply','http://example.com');
 });
 </script>
```

Kindly suggest where the code needs refinement.
Also, as an alternate solution tried Calculated columns (value set to Numeric) and provided the required hyperlink information in the formula section. The hyperlink appears in `Allviews.aspx`, but not visible in `displayform.aspx` or `Newform.aspx`.

Based on inputs from other in the community, it seems the viable option is CSR, so trying with JavaScript and need assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work, added a script editor to the page and add the following modified script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     var setColumnValue = function (column, linkVal) {
     var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + column + "']");

     //this is what I changed    
     columnObj.attr('value',linkVal);
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setColumnValue('Apply','http://example.com'); 
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. I`ve tried adding the script as part of a script editor on the displayform.aspx page and place it below the form. But the JavaScript seems not doing the job as the field value name: Apply, doesn't appears to show any hyperlink.
Later tried changing the value to Salary, below is the code (field name : Salary)

`code` 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setColumnValue('Salary','http://example.com'); 
});

`code`
Above code only shows the changes section, rest all taken as what you had added. Please help

Comment: you have to use the Developer Tools (F12) and get the exact title of the field. (for example, Title field 's title is 'Title Required Field')...so what I am trying to say is that the column title might be different from the display name. The only way to figure this out is by using the Developer Tool. Also check the console tab of the developer tool for errors; it could be something else is throwing an error! Check the updated screen shot.

Comment: thanks so your assistance so far.
Update, I would find the value for Filed: ApplyNow field as per Developer tool as :

<h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_test"></a>ApplyNow</h3>


So my code should show - 

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setColumnValue('SPBookmark_test','http://example.com'); 
});


My understanding, no other change in your code apart from the above?

If yes, I tried but still no success. 

So let me get back to basics, in order to understand if I`ve missed.

Comment: I`m using the javascript on my dispform.aspx file by adding to a script editor and placing it below the form part of dispform.aspx. (Hope that is the correct approach)

Once I get a success, wherein the field name: ApplyNow once cursor placed on it shows the Hyperlink or allows you to click in order to route you to the link (http://www.example.com) then will perform the same action for Newform.aspx.

Hope that is overall the correct approach?

Comment: further update, same result when tested on my SharePoint Online Test platform.

Comment: as far as I know, the way to select an anchor tag by name in jQuery is as follows: $('a[name=SPBookmark_test]')

Comment: tried but the following code, wherein name of the field: Salary and expecting the link to appear when cursor placed on Salary field.

`code` <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     var setColumnValue = function (column, linkVal) {
     var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + column + "']");

     //this is what I changed    
     columnObj.attr('value',linkVal);
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setColumnValue($('a[name=SPBookmark_Salary]'),'http://example.com'); 
});
</script> `code`

Comment: I believe I am little confused at this point. Can you please put a screen shot of what you have now and what you want to do? I am little concerned bcuz you are mentioning when you hover over the salary field and this is was not mentioned before!!!

Comment: here is the screenshot of dispform.aspx

Comment: here is the screenshot of dispform.aspx
http://imgur.com/ocm7MO9
`code` <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     var setColumnValue = function (column, linkVal) {
     var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + column + "']");

     //this is what I changed    
     columnObj.attr('value',linkVal);
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setColumnValue$('a[name=SPBookmark_Salary]','http://example.com'); 
});
</script> `code`

Expectation www.example.com be linked as hyperlink for the field name: Salary. pls sugg ur view.

Comment: it worked. Thanks for yr support. Pls confirm if the link can be accessed.Example- url ca act as a hyperlinl rather just a text wen submitted.

Comment: yes, it should. The only thing I was thinking about is why did you create it as a column, if the link is always the same URL. You can just added a new td at the end of your display form using jQuery like this $('input[title="choose the column name you want this to show up before it"]').parent().parent().parent().before("<td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' style='font-size:14px;'><nobr><a href='www.google.com'>Apply</a></nobr></span></td>");

Comment: please mark it as an answer if you think it is

Comment: that`s a good piece of information. I tried adding the code to dispform.aspx, seems I `ve done something not right. As per your suggestion to choose the column name. 
Well, I wanted to show it before the column name: Other, now here is the confusion. Shall I add the word Other or its a value?
Check what I see from developer tool for column name - 

<td width="113" class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Other"></a>Other</h3></td>

I tried adding the column name and executed the code, can u pls check the code.

Comment: `code` <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[title="Other"]').parent().parent().parent().before("<td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><span class='ms-h3 ms-standardheader' style='font-size:14px;'><nobr><a href='http://www.google.com'>CheckThis</a></nobr></span></td>");
 </script> `code`

Answer (score 0):

@ahmed, Solution by Ahmed worked in my case.

**Code**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 //Code to add url to the Hyperlink field part of Columna name: LinkURL -
     var setColumnValue = function (column, linkVal) {
     var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + column + "']");

     //this is what I changed    
     columnObj.attr('value',linkVal);
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    setColumnValue('Link','www.example.com); 
});
</script>
```